# Can I use sendEmailVerification method for a passwordless purpose? (firebase, flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a multipage (3 pages) account signup that contains

1. Email verification (ONLY enter the email, click send button then verify)
2. Choose the interest categories (if the email is verify)
3. Enter the major and graduation year

I previously used a package that sends OTP to the email that is entered in the textfield and it is no longer supported. So now I am looking at [sendEmailVerification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email) that sends the verification link to the email. However, all the examples I have looked are having both email address AND password in their sign up page. Can I still use that method for my case (passwordlessly)? Please help.

Comment: How and when do you create the user account?

Comment: So I am passing all the info after each page (pass email -> categories -> major and year -> save all of them) and eventually save the new user's gathered info in the method I wrote using Dio

Comment: To use the `sendEmailVerification` method you need that the user exists in order to pass it as the argument of the method. So it is not going to work with your onboarding flow if I understand it correctly. You should create your own email verification email mechanism, for example with Firestore (to store the temporary data needed for the verification) and Cloud Functions (for sending emails).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Email-link-auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/email-link-auth) if you want an email-only login.

Comment: This is indeed the correct approach to allowing password-less sign-in in Firebase. The email-link provider also combines sign-in with email verification, since the only way to sign in is to click the link in the email.

Comment: Okay, so this isn't just for sign in, but also can be used in what I wanna implement? Will it just verify the email? So far, I am using Dio and pass the variable after each page  (1 pass email -> 2 categories -> 3 major and year -> save all of them) , the eventually use the post method to save everything after page 3.